# Optimizing gunicorn and nginx FastAPI deployment

Tags: performance, gunicorn, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy, uvicorn

So I have a cpu-intensive (runs neural networks) FastAPI app run with Uvicorn workers and gunicorn at port 8000. Nginx serves as the reverse proxy.

Currently I only have 1 worker running like so

```bash
gunicorn server:app --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --daemon
```

Using python locust to load test it with 10 concurrent requests, I get around 30% cpu usage and no 503 or 502 responses.

With 2 or more workers however, it has 70-80% cpu usage and I instantly have more than half of the responses being 503 or 502.

```bash
gunicorn server:app --workers 2 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --daemon
```

Using 2 workers seems to be too much, but I also don't really like how only 30% of the cpu is utilized with 1 worker.

How might I change things to take better advantage of resources? I want to improve the speed of the api, but increasing workers doesn't seem to work here.

The machine has 6 vCpu cores and 2.5 gb ram (1.5 gb is usually free while under load, so memory is not an issue). Nginx is just a simple reverse proxy setup.

Comment: Isn't the 30% cpu load caused because only one request at a time can be handled when only one worker is available (assuming you're running blocking code)? The Gunicorn docs hint worker tuning; "A positive integer generally in the 2-4 x $(NUM_CORES) range. You’ll want to vary this a bit to find the best for your particular application’s work load."

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide yeah I saw that, but running 2+ workers just makes it fail as I mentioned despite only ~70% cpu usage. There's something wrong with what I'm doing somewhere I suspect.